# How do I access the code for a glade/gtk project I am working on

Tags: c++, gtk, glade

I am building a GUI for an encryption program my brother made. I want to learn more C++ so I am taking this opportunity to do so. I cant figure out how link my text editor Atom to the project. I can code the parts in C++ I just need help figuring out how exactly I attach the code I make to correspond with the GUI I have structured in Glade. Any resources would be very helpful.

Comment: From [glade.gnome.org](https://glade.gnome.org/): _The user interfaces designed in Glade are saved as XML, and by using the GtkBuilder GTK object these can be loaded by applications dynamically as needed._ So, I strongly believe you're looking for [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html), don't you?

Comment: Yes that helped a lot, it led me to this line of code   
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv[]);

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("name of .glade file")